# Не работает кастомный JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

Имеется json:

```
{
    "access_token": "xxx",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "refresh_token": "yyy",
    "created_at": 1524344276
}
```

`created_at` возвращает время в секундах от 1970 года, поэтому модель для этого `json` написал следующую:

```
public class OAuth2Token
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken  { get; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType    { get; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int    ExpiresIn    { get; } //Seconds

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at"), JsonConverter(typeof(SecondEpochConverter))]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
}
```

И для конвертации секунд в `DateTime` использую конвертер:

```
public class SecondEpochConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(((DateTime)value - _epoch).TotalSeconds.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) { return null; }
        return _epoch.AddSeconds((long)reader.Value);
    }
}
```

Однако при попытке распарсить срабатывает исключение:

`JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 1. Path 'created_at', line 1, position 221.`

**UPD:**

Для работы с автоматическими свойствами без сеттеров установлена следующая настройка:

```
jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings //for (de-)serialization get-autoproperty
{
    ContractResolver = new PrivateSetterContractResolver()
};
```

([Github](https://github.com/TheInsaneBro/PrivateSetterContractResolver) и [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PrivateSetterContractResolver/2.1.0) решения)
и вызывается десериализация вот так:

```
//T - в данном случае OAuth2Token
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Comment: Тык... он у вас даже не запускается: поставьте брейкпойнты на методы - увидите, что отладка не заходит туда.

Comment: @AK так я вроде указал аттрибут над свойством. что ещё надо сделать, чтобы заходил?

Comment: Ну, чтобы установить свойство - нужен сеттер ;) Геттеры вижу. ;)

Comment: Посмотрите пример: https://danielwertheim.se/json-net-private-setters-nuget/ - видите там `private set:`?

Comment: @AK ну к примеру, я сейчас оставил сеттер только у проблемного свойства `CreatedAt`, а у остальных только геттеры и оно работает..

Comment: @AK видимо, какая-то проблема возникает только в случае с конвертацией.. иначе работает и без сеттеров =/

Comment: @AK оставил во всех полях только геттеры, а в проблемном добавил приватный сеттер.. наверное придётся так) | http://pastexen.com/i/LdM7KMhXwi.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли сеттеры.

Рабочий пример:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = @"{
    ""access_token"": ""xxx"",
    ""token_type"": ""bearer"",
    ""expires_in"": 86400,
    ""refresh_token"": ""yyy"",
    ""created_at"": 1524344276
}";
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuth2Token>(source);
    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class SecondEpochConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static readonly DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue(((DateTime)value - _epoch).TotalSeconds.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) { return null; }
        return _epoch.AddSeconds((long)reader.Value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class OAuth2Token
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; } //Seconds

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SecondEpochConverter))]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Если заменить JsonConverter обратно на DateTimeConverterBase и убрать CanConvert - тоже будет работать)

---

С учётом вскрывшихся подробностей. Посмотрите [пример](https://danielwertheim.se/json-net-private-setters-nuget/):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings  
{
    ContractResolver = new PrivateSetterContractResolver()
};

var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json, settings);
```

где модель:

```
public class Model  
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }
}
```

That's it.

PS Можно поставить только на одно это свойство с кастомным конвертером.

Comment: по поводу сеттеров: у меня, по идее, стоит вот такая настройка:  `jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new PrivateSetterContractResolver() };`

Comment: она должна позволять парсить автоматические свойства только с геттерами

Comment: хм.. сейчас добавил сеттеры и заработало. но проблема в том, что мне не нужны сеттеры =/ объект инициализируется через json и больше не доступен для записи =/

Comment: Могу удалить ответ. С вас - дописать в вопрос существенные подробности. Ранее в нём ничего про кастомные настройки не было.

Comment: Дописал ответ, но поскольку РосКомНадзор блокирует github - не могу установить пакет и проверить. Попробуйте сами поставить на это свойство private set

Comment: ответил выше.. так и сделал.. работает.. а по поводу гитхаб... попробуйте с nuget взять)

Comment: наверное стоит изменить ответ на рекомендацию установить в конкретное свойство `private set` вместо кода, практически идентичного тому, что есть в вопросе)