# Десериализация json во вложенный класс

Tags: c#, json

Всем привет. Есть, примерно, следующий json файл:

```json
[{
        "a": "AA",
        "aa": "aaAA",
        "d": "DD",
        "dd": "ddDD",
        "c": "CC",
        "q": "QQ",
},
{
        "a": "AA",
        "aa": "aaAA",
        "d": "DD",
        "dd": "ddDD",
        "c": "CC",
        "q": "QQ",
}]
```

Полей в данном json значительно больше. Этот json нужно десериализовать в следующий класс:

```cs
public class Example
{
        [JsonIgnore]
        public A A { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public D D { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("c")]
        public string C { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("q")]
        public string Q { get; set; }
}
```

где класс **A**:

```cs
public class A
{
        [JsonProperty("a")]
        public string a { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("aa")]
        public string AA { get; set; }
}
```

Так же и с классом **D**. Первое что пришло в голову, раздельно десериализовать каждый класс и объеденить их все в классе **Example**. Сразу не понравилась идея, из-за будущих сложностей при расширении класса. Может есть лучший способ десериализации не вложенного json во вложенные классы?

Comment: А чем сериализуете? Смотрели в сторону https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему ваш json подразумевает один класс со всеми строковыми полями, а вы пытаетесь создать модель, выделив часть полей в отдельные классы, зачем ? тут логично либо модель сделать простой - один класс и 7 полей, либо json изменить под вашу модель с вложенными классами

Comment: @Denis смотрю в сторону newtonsoft json и кастомного converter, который будет объединять данные в класс  Example.

Comment: @PavelPopov json получаю со стороны и никак не могу его изменить. В нем значительно больше полей, часть этих полей сгруппировал по общим признакам и вынес в отдельные классы. Чтобы не путаться в большом обилии полей в классе.

Comment: А вы не группируйте. Какой структуры Json пришёл -- так честно и описывайте. А уже когда распарсите то, что есть - конвертируйте в нужную вам форму. Это самый простой и поддерживаемый путь.

Comment: @AK Вы правы. Но, пока для меня более удобен вариант с кастомным converter, если не получится добавить JsonProperty. Буду брать сырой класс со всеми полями и преобразовывать его, как душе угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Технически, если вы используете Json.Net то при парсинге json вы можете модифицировать как угодно получающуюся структуру подменяя нужные фрагменты JNode (я приводил примеры: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906894/213987), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/954681/213987), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830323/213987), [четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/817460/213987)...)

У вас придётся вешать кастомный конвертер прямо на класс и знать его внутреннюю структуру, как-то так:

```
public class NestedConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Type type = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType);
        bool isNullable = (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) != null);

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (!isNullable)
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for type {0} at path {1}", objectType.Name, reader.Path));
            return null;
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            var nestedA = new NestedA();
            var nestedD = new NestedD();
            var q = "";
            foreach(JProperty abc in token.Children())
            {
                // TODO: Напрашивается рефлексия?
                
                if(abc.Name == nameof(NestedA.a))
                    nestedA.a = abc.Value.ToString();

                ...

                if (abc.Name == nameof(SomeClass.q))
                    q = abc.Value.ToString();
            }
            return new SomeClass
            {
                NestedA = nestedA,
                NestedD = nestedD,
                q = q,
            };
        }
        
        throw new Exception("Вот сейчас прям совсем неожиданно было");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И такие классы:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(NestedConverter))]
public class SomeClass
{
    public NestedA NestedA { get; set; }
    public NestedD NestedD { get; set; }
    public string q { get; set; }
}

public class NestedA
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string AA { get; set; }
}

public class NestedD
{
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string DD { get; set; }
}
```

Использование:

```
var source = @"[{
    ""a"": ""AA"",
    ""aa"": ""aaAA"",
    ""d"": ""DD"",
    ""dd"": ""ddDD"",
    ""c"": ""CC"",
    ""q"": ""QQ"",
    },
    {
            ""a"": ""AA"",
            ""aa"": ""aaAA"",
            ""d"": ""DD"",
            ""dd"": ""ddDD"",
            ""c"": ""CC"",
            ""q"": ""QQ"",
    }]";
var parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass[]>(source);
parsed.Dump();
```

Вуаля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я бы в вашем случае прислушался к рекомендациям сделать отдельно POCO-классы для сериализации и отдельно - модифицировать после в любой нужный вид. Это намного проще и нагляднее, чем потом читать колдовство разбора json.

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что и нужно было. А можно как-то на поле q повесить атрибут [JsonProperty("q")]. Чтобы в ручную не  делать так: `if (abc.Name == nameof(SomeClass.q)) {q = abc.Value.ToString();}`

Comment: @Chisel Нет, раз начался кастом - то дальше уже кастом. Но облегчить работу себе можно. Именно навесив атрибуты и потом закатав рукава использовать рефлексию: собрать все свойства класса и атрибуты, для полученной коллекции сравнивать пришедшее с тем, что сохранили в кеш (я всегда сохраняю в статический словарь, т.к. рефлексия штука медленная), потом при наличии совпадений в зависимости от типа приводить .Value к нужному... Это вполне реально, просто нужно ещё отдельно написать кучу кода. И это будет более универсально, да. Хотя уж совсем универсально не получится.

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз большое. Тогда не вижу смысла развивать эту идею. Перейду на сырой класс со всеми полями и буду его маппить, как мне удобно.

Comment: @Chisel Про что вам и в комментариях и говорили. Но иногда нужно посмотреть на альтернативные варианты, чтобы действительно понять, что в данном конкретном случае лучше в эту сторону не идти.