# JSON "правильная" Десериализация

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Получаю от сервера ответ в виде JSON:

```
[{
    "name": "Colombia",
    "alpha2Code": "CO",
    "alpha3Code": "COL",
    "capital": "Bogotá"
}]
```

Определение класса:

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alpha2Code { get; set; }
    public string Alpha3Code { get; set; }
    public City Capital { get; set; }
}
```

Как правильно десериализовать JSON, в котором "capital" строка, а в объекте столица представлена объектом типа City.

Я интересуюсь именно как **"правильно"** это реализовать с вашей точки зрения. Решение этому ведь уже есть, просто я плохо искал?

P.S: Я думаю в сторону создания DTO, где Capital будет типа string, а потом из него конструировать объект Country.

Благодарю.

Comment: Да, вы правильно думаете в сторону dto. Технически, конечно [можно дополнить штатную десериализацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1190062/213987) кастомным парсингом JToken'ов, но это сложно - вы сами через полгода с трудом вспомните что и для чего делалось, а уж править это удовольствие сомнительное.

Comment: @AK, как-то сложно у тебя. Да и если использовать `JsonConverter` для свойства - уже будет проще. К тому же можно воспользоваться [`JsonConstructor`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) в котором добавить логику для этого поля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я покажу свою идею, как это побороть без написания сложных конвертеров. Смысл здесь в реализации логики данных в самой модели. Написал бы комментарий, да не влезет это всё туда.

*Использую атрибуты, совместимые с `System.Text.Json`.*

```cs
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alpha2Code { get; set; }
    public string Alpha3Code { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("capital")]
    public string CapitalName
    {
        get => Capital?.Name;
        set => Capital = new City(value);
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public City Capital { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public City(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Если сериализатор позволяет, то свойство `CapitalName` можно вообще сделать приватным.

Я не претендую на гениальность и не могу утверждать, насколько правильный или неправильный данный подход. Но с ходу минусов у такой реализации я не вижу.

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ. Очень интересная реализация, выглядит очень неплохо. Возьму на вооружение :)

Comment: По факту работать будет, до тех пор, пока какой-нибудь Алжир не построит свой Лондон и не сделает его столицей. =)

Comment: @Blackmeser не вижу проблем добавить еще одну перегрузку конструктора в будущем, если возникнет такая потребность.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить ещё один способ.
Делаем в классе City оператор неявного [преобразования](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) из строки:

```
public class City
{
    public static implicit operator City(string value) => new City { Name = value };
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

В результате десериализация проходит успешно.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(json);
```

Можно ли назвать это "правильным"? Дело вкуса.
Обычно принято использовать конвертеры. Во-первых, они позволяют набить кучу кода. Во-вторых, они привычны большинству разрабов. В третьих, потому что!